# Reshaping data frame to create list of unique values in column

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

I have the data set:

```
df <- data.frame(g = c("X", "X", "Y", "Z", "Y", "Z", "Z"),
                 r = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A"))
```

And I would to manipulate the data in a way that I get the result:

g | r
X | A B
Y | A C
Z | A C

So for each g all the unique r values are listed. I can use the reshape package for this. But I would like to be able to do this with standard R, because the script will be shared with people with a very limited knowledge of R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `aggregate()`?

```
aggregate( df$r , by = list( df$g ) , function(x) paste0( sort( unique(x) ) , collapse = "" ) )
#  Group.1  x
#1       X AB
#2       Y AC
#3       Z AC
```

Comment: You can also use formula style and use the `data` argument to avoid writing `df$·`: `aggregate(r ~ g, function(x) paste0( sort( unique(x) ) , collapse = "" ), data=df)`

Comment: I actually prefer a `list` to `paste` in these cases to retain the flexibility of doing further analysis if required. `aggregate(r ~ g, df, function(x) unique(sort(as.character(x))), simplify=FALSE)`. But this does answer their question as presented, so +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
dg <- data.frame(
  g = levels(df$g),
  r = tapply(df$r, df$g, function(n) {paste(sort(unique(n)), collapse = " ")})
  )
> dg
  g   r
X X A B
Y Y A C
Z Z A C
```